# what is the solution for spark cluster libs version is lower than my project's dependency in Gradle

Tags: apache-spark

My project has to rely on dependency which used higher version httpcore (4.3.2), but on the cluster, Spark is using 4.2.5. After I build the fat jar with Gradle shadowJar plugin, I found the 4.3.2 is in the fat jar. But when I ran the spark program with spark-submit, 4.2.5 was always loaded.

So what's the general solution to handle these kind of usecase : your dependency is using higher version jar than Spark using.

Comment: Using maven and the maven-shade-plugin, it is possible to relocate your dependencies. I am guessing the Gradle shadowJar plugin has the same feauture. Edit : this looks like it : http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/#relocating_packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the conflict by creating a shaded JAR.

Spark executors had a dependency issue when running on yarn mode.

Resolved by shading my dependency in my Gradle project as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

shadowJar {
    // shading these two packages as they clash with spark executor env
    relocate 'org.apache.http', 'com.org.shaded.http'
    zip64 = true
}

build {
    dependsOn shadowJar
}
```

ref: https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/relocation/